# Precise proof of a statement required

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

[image]

In the last line , the author says that `in a bounded sequence with unique limit, if infinitely many outside terms exist outside a particular neighbourhood of the unique Limit Point l, then it will lead to another Limit Point of the sequence`.

This seems intuitive in the sense that since it is a bounded sequence with unique limit point, there can not be cluster of points outside the any neighbourhood of $l$ which is under consideration. But can we prove it rigourously and precisely ?

Comment: WLOG suppose there are infinitely many points $< l - \varepsilon$. Then define a new sequence with just these points, and by B.W this will have a convergent subsequence, hence another limit point of the original sequence.

Comment: Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Thanks for helping out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n_k$ the $k$<sup>th</sup> index such that $S_{n_k}\notin(l-\varepsilon,l+\varepsilon)$. Since $(S_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded, $(S_{n_k})_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded too, and therefore it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir

Comment: I'm glad I could help.